# Not able to drop table in sqlite database in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

In my application, whenever the user is pressing the logout button, i need to drop a table and create the same table again. For this, i am using this code:

```
int result = sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db);

if(result == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *dropTable = "DROP table RegisterTable";
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, dropTable,
                       -1, &statement, NULL);

    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"table dropped");
    }

    else
    {
        NSLog(@"table not dropped");
    }
}

else
{
    NSLog(@"Not opened for dropping");
}
```

However, every time i am getting "table not dropped"..

Comment: Check your database path

Comment: The database path is OK. I have checked it. Opening the DB doesnot give any error.

Comment: Midhun is right: if you're getting "Not opened for dropping" the database is NOT open. You haven't even tried to drop a table at that moment.

Comment: see the edited question.. i made a mistake while writing the question.

Comment: Are you sure table exists in your database? Try to perform some select or something to check.

Comment: Call  sqlite3_errmsg() for information why a SQLite call failed.

Comment: And what is the return code you get when it fails?  And what does sqlite3_errmsg say?

Comment: If you open a non-existent database, it gets created.  So you very easily can have the wrong path.  Actually bothering to examine return codes and error messages would give you some clues.

Comment: ok.. i will try out all suggestions made here and get back..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the result code from both your prepare statement and step.

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html

The comments are right in that it is highly likely the table does not actually exist in your database.